# View Child error to access CdkVirtualScrollViewport inside of ng-template

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I used angular CDK Overlay and inside my overlay I have some options which are wrap by Virtual scroll, Now I want to access the virtual scroll inside my component by View Child but getting error continuously. I can't get any solution for this. Here is my code example,

```
HTML:

  <ng-template cdkConnectedOverlay cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClass="cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop" [cdkConnectedOverlayHasBackdrop]="true" [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger" [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isMenuOpen" (detach)="isMenuOpen = false" (backdropClick)="isMenuOpen = false">

          <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50">
            <mat-option style=";height: 50px;" (click)="optionClicked($event, data)" *cdkVirtualFor="let data of filteredData;">
              <div (click)="optionClicked($event, data)">
                <mat-checkbox [checked]="data.selected">
                  {{ data.skillName }}
                </mat-checkbox>
              </div>
            </mat-option>
          </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

</ng-template>


TS:

@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) cdkVirtualScrollViewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    
     this.cdkVirtualScrollViewport.elementScrolled().pipe(
       map(() => this.cdkVirtualScrollViewport.measureScrollOffset('bottom')),
       pairwise(),
       filter(([y1, y2]) => (y2 < y1) && (y2 < 70)),
       tap(() => this.isLoading = true),
       switchMap((_) => {..API CALL..})).subscribe(...)
....
}

ERROR:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elementScrolled')
    at MultiselectAutocompleteComponent.ngAfterViewInit (multiselect-autocomplete.component.ts:212:36)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2449:22)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2418:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2369:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10413:21)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:11401:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:10132:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10392:13)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:11355:17)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10366:9)
```

I want the CDK Virtual Scroll View Port reference in AfterViewInit so that I can get the bottom scroll event. Because I don't want to fetch all thousands of responses at a time, I want to call API when user go to bottom.

Comment: What error do you get ? is The ViewChild undefined ?

Comment: yes @MatthieuRiegler

Answer (score 1):

The `ViewChild` will only be defined once the template is rendered.

You could make the property a setter to be notified when the `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` is initialized.

```
  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) set viewPort(vp: CdkVirtualScrollViewport) {
     if(vp) {
       this.cdkVirtualScrollViewport.elementScrolled()
       ...
     }
  } ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `<ng-template>` element.

[`With <ng-template>, you can define template content that is only being rendered by Angular when you, whether directly or indirectly, specifically instruct it to do so, allowing you to have full control over how and when the content is displayed.`](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template)

Unless, you explicitly render the template, the content won't be rendered in the DOM and ViewChild won't be able to pick it up, even not AfterViewInit.

Wrap it in an `<ng-container>` instead.